# Set default parameter value from another paramater's value

Tags: c++, parameters

Is it possible to achieve such functionality, that parameter's value would default to another parameter's value if not specified?

Example:

```
class Health
{
public:
    // If current is not specified, its value defaults to max's value
    Health(int max, int current = max) : max_(max), current_(current) { }
    int max_;
    int current_;
};
```

As it is now, I am getting a compile error:

```
error: 'max' was not declared in this scope
Health(int max, int current = max) : max_(max), current_(current) { }
                              ^
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to provide overload:

```
class Health
{
public:
    Health(int max, int current) : max_(max), current_(current) { }

    Health(int max) : max_(max), current_(max) {}
    // or `Health(int max) : Health(max, max) {}` since C++11

    int max_;
    int current_;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can default the parameter to a value that should not be accepted and then you  and then check using the `?` operator in the initialization

```
class Health
{
public:
    // If current is not specified, its value defaults to max's value
    Health(int max, int current = 0) : max_(max), current_(current == 0 ? max : current) { }
    int max_;
    int current_;
};
```

Comment: What if 0 is a valid value for current?

Comment: or use `const int* current=nullptr` (or `optional<int>`), but it seems over complicated.

Comment: @Jarod42 The pointer would be super-ugly for the caller ("what do you mean I cannot pass a literal?!"), but `optional` is fair game, I'd say.